# Can someone please explain to me the logic of this mysql select query values?

Tags: mysql

```
Concat(Date_format(Date_add(Date_format(Str_to_date(
                                               products_options_values,
                                               '%m-%d-%Y'
                                                      ),
                                                      '%Y-%m-%d'),
                                             INTERVAL(2-Dayofweek(Date_format(
                                             Str_to_date(
                                             products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y'
                                             )
                                             , '%Y-%m-%d')))day), '%b%d'), '-',
       Date_format(Date_add(Date_format(Str_to_date(products_options_values,
                                        '%m-%d-%Y'
       )
       ,
       '%Y-%m-%d'
       ),
       INTERVAL( 8 - Dayofweek( Date_format(Str_to_date(products_options_values,
       '%m-%d-%Y'
       ), '%Y-%m-%d')) )day), '%b%d'))
       AS week_dates,
       Week(Date_format(Str_to_date(products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y'),
            '%Y-%m-%d'))
                   AS weekdays
```

I need to implement the above mysql date calculation logic in jquery.
This is part of a mysql select statement to get dates. But I failed to understand what is happening exactly with this date calculations, can someone please explain this?

Comment: Can you please first format the query correctly

Comment: err how exactly do I do that? moreover, I don't think you need the other fields and stuff like WHERE, ORDER BY are needed to explain just this two calculations

Comment: I mean you should indent the query properly for example `concat(*New line here*date_format(*New line here*DATE_ADD` and so on

Comment: I looked at the query, but I think this can be done a lot easier. Is it an option to redo the query? There are just to many things going on for me to correctly see the use of this particular query.

Comment: I am not doing the query, I am supposed to rewrite that same calculation logic in javascript, so I need to understand the logic

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11214/discussion-between-aoi-and-rick-hoving)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding code like this is to work from the *inside* outwards.  A quick glance through your code quickly reveals that the innermost function calls are the same:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

The innermost of those two function calls, [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), takes the string in `products_options_values` and converts it to a MySQL `DATE` value by parsing it according to the format given in the second argument (i.e. US-style *month-day-year*).  The outermost function call, [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), takes that resulting `DATE` value and formats it in the form given by *its* second argument (i.e. *year-month-day*).

That is, together those calls convert a date represented in US-style form into a more international format.  Rewriting the rest of your query using `international_date` in place of those calls:

```
Concat(
  Date_format(
    Date_add(
      international_date,
      INTERVAL(
        2 - Dayofweek(international_date)
     ) day
   ),
   '%b%d'
  ),
  '-',
  Date_format(
    Date_add(
      international_date,
      INTERVAL(
        8 - Dayofweek(international_date)
      ) day
    ),
    '%b%d'
  )
) AS week_dates,
Week(international_date) AS weekdays
```

The [`DAYOFWEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function returns the given date's day of the week as an integer from 1 to 7 (where 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday).  Therefore, adding `2 - DAYOFWEEK(international_date)` days will give the Monday of the same week; and adding `8 - DAYOFWEEK(international_date)` will give the Sunday of the following week.  That is precisely what the [`DATE_ADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) functions are doing.

Those dates (Monday of the same week and Sunday of the following week) are then formatted in a specific form (three letter month and two-digit day, e.g. `Jan14` or `May18`) and concatenated with [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/string-functions.html#function_concat) using a separating hyphen.  The result is given the alias `week_dates`.

There is also another column in the resultset which is given the alias `weekdays`; this holds the value of the [`WEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function as applied to `international_date` (that is, its week of the year).